# confusing Page_Load behavior

Tags: asp.net

This is what I'm trying:

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

```
String test = "hi ";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


        test = test + test;
        Button1.Value =  test;

}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1.Value = "u're trolled !";
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

}

when the page is first loaded it shows "hi hi " as the Button1's value. But whenever I click Button2, it shows "u're trolled !" as Button1's value. My question is if the page is postback every time I click the button and the Page_Load is called, then why does it shows "u're trolled !" instead of appending "hi" ?? Isn't the Page_Load called every time the page reloads ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to know which value come when :

```
String test = "hi ";

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    test = test + test;
    Button1.Value +=  test;

}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Button1.Value += "u're trolled !";
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help :) but why always test gets "hi hi" ? rather appending to the previous value ? (don't laugh ! :P I've just started learning)

Comment: Its great that you start learning ASP.net.I am giving you some basic links please read them carefully and you will get the answer of your question in detail

http://frejnorling.wordpress.com/2011/02/21/the-asp-net-application-life-cycle-page-life-cycle-and-control-life-cycle/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: thanks but what about test getting value "hi hi " every time even after test=test+test ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the ASP.NET Page Life Cycle, as Code addict said its the sequence of events that causing the issue for you.

Following link will be very helpful for you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx